# Process a compressed gz file to create table schema using Glue Data crawler

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a compressed gzip file in an S3 bucket.  The files will be uploaded to the S3 bucket daily by the client.  The gzip when uncompressed will contain 10 files in CSV format, but with the same schema only.  My objective is to process the gzip file, use a Data crawler to create table schema, and then load / merge all data to a new single table as a parquet file.

Can a Glue crawler read a gz file and create create tables as per the list of files.  Please help with a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to find a way? Did it require custom classifiers? Please share any way you found. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can read gzip & zip csv's

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-classifier.html#classifier-built-in